# Spring boot Email configuration for cPanel mail

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, cpanel

**My SSL/TLS setting for mail is like this-**

```
username- username
password - *******
outgoing server- mail.example.com 
SMTP port - 465
```

I used this detail in my spring boot application.properties file

**application.properties**

```
spring.mail.username=noreply@example.com
spring.mail.password=*******
spring.mail.host=mail.example.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

When I am sending the mail, the loader is just spinning and I am not getting any error.
I have changed the port from 465 to 587 and also changed the host from mail to smtp but still not receiving any email.

Comment: What does the logs say? Can you see any exception or error in the logs?

Comment: @AyushiJain There is no exception or error in the console. When I click on the submit button browser's loader  continuously spins.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem. I had forgotten to add this line in my code-

**mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("noreply@example.com", "Example"));**

also I modified the properties from

```
spring.mail.username=noreply@example.com
spring.mail.password=*******
spring.mail.host=mail.example.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

to

```
 spring.mail.username=noreply@example.com
 spring.mail.password=*******
 spring.mail.host=mail.example.com
 spring.mail.port=465
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class= javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```